# Strange React error when using a component with name Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have two simple React components:

```
// Array.js

import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const factor = 10
const Array = ({array}) =>
    <div className="array">
        {array.map(v => v * factor)
            .map((h, i) => <Column key={i}
                                   height={h}/>)}
    </div>

const Column = ({height}) =>
    <div className="column" style={{height: `${height}px`}}/>

Array.propTypes = {
    array: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default Array
```

and

```
// ArraySort.js

import React from 'react'
import Array from 'src/components/Array'

const array = [2, 4, 6, 7, 10, 7, 6, 1]

class ArraySort extends React.Component {

     state = {array}

    render() {

        const {array} = this.state

        console.log('array', array)
        return <div className="array-sort">
            <Array array={array}/>
        </div>
    }
}

export default ArraySort
```

Strangely when I try to render `ArraySort` I get an error:

```
Array.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Array (Array.js:7)
    at new ArraySort (bundle.js:35363)
    at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:9760)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:10215)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:10605)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:12573)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:12682)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:1299)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:1338)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:1195)
Array @ Array.js:7
ArraySort @ bundle.js:35363
constructClassInstance @ react-dom.development.js:9760
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:10215
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:10605
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:12573
workLoop @ react-dom.development.js:12682
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:1299
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:1338
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:1195
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:12800
scheduleUpdateImpl @ react-dom.development.js:13185
scheduleUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:13124
scheduleTopLevelUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:13395
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:13425
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:17105
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:13256
renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:17104
render @ react-dom.development.js:17129
(anonymous) @ index.js:17
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap d8c366268449b6de2a48:19
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:2545
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap d8c366268449b6de2a48:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap d8c366268449b6de2a48:62
(anonymous) @ bootstrap d8c366268449b6de2a48:62
react-dom.development.js:8305 The above error occurred in the <ArraySort> component:
    in ArraySort
    in div
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
You can learn more about error boundaries at -----.
logCapturedError$1 @ react-dom.development.js:8305
captureError @ react-dom.development.js:12993
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:12825
scheduleUpdateImpl @ react-dom.development.js:13185
scheduleUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:13124
scheduleTopLevelUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:13395
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:13425
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:17105
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:13256
renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:17104
render @ react-dom.development.js:17129
(anonymous) @ index.js:17
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap d8c366268449b6de2a48:19
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:2545
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap d8c366268449b6de2a48:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap d8c366268449b6de2a48:62
(anonymous) @ bootstrap d8c366268449b6de2a48:62
Array.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Array (Array.js:7)
    at new ArraySort (bundle.js:35363)
    at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:9760)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:10215)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:10605)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:12573)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:12682)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:1299)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:1338)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:1195)
```

This works if I import `Array.js` under a different name i.e. `ArrayComponent`.

The projects uses:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.3"
  }
```

What might be the cause of this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array` [Is a predefined name in the `javascript` language and its usage should be avoided](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)

Quote:

> In addition to the above reserved words, you'd better avoid the
>   following identifiers as names of JavaScript variables. These are
>   predefined names of implementation-dependent JavaScript objects,
>   methods, or properties (and, arguably, some should have been reserved
>   words)

I would also recommend initiate the state inside the `constructor`.

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment

> Why do you recommend initializing state inside constructor?

Because this method is part of the `React.Component` [life cycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

Quote from the [DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor):

> The constructor is the right place to initialize state. To do so, just
>   assign an object to this.state

Comment: Why do you recommend initializing state inside `constructor`?